# Rigid body - Fall in fron of camera / loopable

Tags: particles, loop

I'm doing a footage with camera flying through scene, and objects are falling from top, sticking (and moving backwards) at ground plane.

Since footage has to be about a 2-3 minutes, I'd like to render only a little portion and loop it.

I believe the easiest way would be to create some particles, convert them into objects, apply rigid body modifier to all of them, and finally bake them into keyframes.

However, I don't need them to fall all at once. I need them to fall in front of camera as far the camera move towards scene.
Even more - I'd like to loop the animation, so object distribution has to be semi-random.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Initially wrong approach was chosen.

I installed a brilliant Animation Nodes addon, which did the job perfectly.